# How to send httponly cookies client side when using next-auth credentials provider?

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm creating a next js application, using next-auth to handle authentication.

I have an external backend api, so I'm using Credentials Provider.

The problem is that the backend sends httponly cookies, but those are not being attached to the browser when i make a request client side.

In /pages/api/[...auth].js

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import Providers from 'next-auth/providers';
import clientAxios from '../../../config/configAxios'

export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
        Providers.Credentials({
            async authorize(credentials) {
                try {
                    const login = await clientAxios.post('/api/login', {
                        username: credentials.username,
                        password: credentials.password,
                        is_master: credentials.is_master
                    })


                    const info = login.data.data.user
                    const token = {
                        accessToken: login.data.data.access_token,
                        expiresIn: login.data.data.expires_in,
                        refreshToken: login.data.data.refresh_token
                    }
                    // I can see cookies here
                    const cookies = login.headers['set-cookie']

                    return { info, token, cookies }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                    throw (Error(error.response.data.M))
                }
            }
        })
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async jwt(token, user, account, profile, isNewUser) {
            if (token) {
               // Here cookies are set but only in server side
               clientAxios.defaults.headers.common['Cookie'] = token.cookies
            }
            if (user) {
                token = {
                    user: user.info,
                    ...user.token,
                }
            }

            return token
        },
        async session(session, token) {
            // Add property to session, like an access_token from a provider.
            session.user = token.user
            session.accessToken = token.accessToken
            session.refreshToken = token.refreshToken

            return session
        }
    },
    session: {
        jwt: true
    }
})
```

my axios config file

```js
import axios from 'axios';

const clientAxios = axios.create({

    baseURL: process.env.backendURL,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers:{
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    }

});

export default clientAxios;
```

a page component

```js
import { getSession } from "next-auth/client";
import clientAxios from "../../../config/configAxios";
import { useEffect } from "react"

export default function PageOne (props) {
    useEffect(async () => {
      // This request fails, cookies are not sent
      const response = await clientAxios.get('/api/info');
    }, [])

    return (
        <div>
           <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps (context) {
    const session = await getSession(context)

    if (!session) {
        return {
            redirect: {
                destination: '/login',
                permanent: false
            }
        }
    }

    // This request works
    const response = await clientAxios.get('/api/info');
    
    return {
        props: {
            session,
            info: response.data
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

After time of researching I have figured it out.

I had to make a change in /pages/api/auth in the way I'm exporting NextAuth.

Instead of

```js
export default NextAuth({
    providers: [
       ...
    ]

})
```

Export it like this, so we can have access to request and response object

```js
export default (req, res) => {
    return NextAuth(req, res, options)
}
```

But to access them in the options object, we can make it a callback

```js
const nextAuthOptions = (req, res) => {
    return {
        providers: [
           ...
        ]
    }
}

export default (req, res) => {
    return NextAuth(req, res, nextAuthOptions(req, res))
}
```

To send a cookie back to the frontend from the backed we must add a 'Set-Cookie' header in the respond

```js
res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', ['cookie_name=cookie_value'])
```

The complete code would be

```js
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';

const nextAuthOptions = (req, res) => {
    return {
        providers: [
           CredentialsProvider({
                async authorize(credentials) {
                   try {                      
                        const response = await axios.post('/api/login', {
                            username: credentials.username,
                            password: credentials.password
                        })

                        const cookies = response.headers['set-cookie']

                        res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookies)
                        
                        return response.data
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error)
                        throw (Error(error.response))
                    } 
                }
           })
        ]
    }
}

export default (req, res) => {
    return NextAuth(req, res, nextAuthOptions(req, res))
}
```

#### Update - Typescript example

Create a type for the callback nextAuthOptions

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';

type NextAuthOptionsCallback = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => NextAuthOptions
```

Combining everything

```js
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next';
import NextAuth, { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth';
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials';
import axios from 'axios'

type NextAuthOptionsCallback = (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => NextAuthOptions

const nextAuthOptions: NextAuthOptionsCallback = (req, res) => {
     return {
        providers: [
           CredentialsProvider({
                credentials: {
                },
                async authorize(credentials) {
                   try {                      
                        const response = await axios.post('/api/login', {
                            username: credentials.username,
                            password: credentials.password
                        })

                        const cookies = response.headers['set-cookie']

                        res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', cookies)

                        return response.data
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.log(error)
                        throw (Error(error.response))
                    } 
                }
           })
        ],
        callbacks: {
            ...
        },
        session: {
            ...
        }
    }
}

export default (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
    return NextAuth(req, res, nextAuthOptions(req, res))
}
```

Comment: Do you think I can do the same using fetch rather than axios? The example does not work with fetch.

Comment: You probably need to use a `.then` after your request and convert the response to json

Comment: this works ok and we can get the cookie from the backend. but the problem is that the cookie stays in the header even after signout. how should we handle this?

Comment: @amiryeganeh httponly cookies cannot be removed on client side. This must be handled on the backend. To expire the cookie, when you logout the backend should respond the cookie that you want to remove with the same parameters (name, path, domain, ...) but with a expiration time lower than the current time, for example "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT"

Comment: Im trying this but with typescript but im not getting it to work :- ( it complains when i try to access any other property on nextAuthOptions, Providers works fine... but like accessing session or the callbacks it gets upset with me. Anyone got it to work with an example with Typescript?

Comment: @ScreamoIsDead I updated the answer with an example with typescript

Comment: My API calls' Request Headers are still missing Cookies, could you please provide a link to a working Github repo ?

Comment: with this solution, how do you use `getServerSession(req,res, nextAuthOption(req,res))`? there's an type error

Comment: @SaulMontilla Looks like it doesn't work like that anymore. I get error 'res.setHeader is not a function'

Answer (score 2):

To remove cookie in nextAuth after signing out, I used the following block of code - set the cookie parameters to match what you have for the cookie to be expired - Use the SignOut event in [...nextauth].js file

```
export default async function auth(req, res) {
    return await NextAuth(req, res, {
        ...    
        events: {
            async signOut({ token }) {
                res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", "cookieName=deleted;Max-Age=0;path=/;Domain=.example.com;");
            },
        },
        ...
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using NextJS 14 app router with next-auth V5 (beta version at the time of writing this), this will likely be your export from the `./auth.ts` file:

```js
export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth(authConfig);
```

In that case, after getting the response from the server that includes the `set-cookie` header, you can use the `cookies()` function from `next/headers` to set the cookie on the browser.

First step is to parse the cookie, which you can accomplish with either the [cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie) module or the built in `querystring` module, then extracting the name of the cookie and its value, and lastly setting it using the `cookies().set()` method, with the same details as was received from the backend.

```js
// ./auth.ts

import { cookies } from "next/headers";
import qs from "querystring";
...
export const authConfig = {
...
    providers: [
        Credentials({
            async authorize(credentials) {
            ...
                const res = await fetch(`api/auth/endpoint`, {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(credentials),
                    credentials: "include",
                });
                // Check if the response is ok here
                // Parse the cookie string with querystring module
                const setCookie = qs.decode(
                    res.headers.get("set-cookie") as string,
                    "; ",
                    "="
                ); // cast this to a type with the structure of the cookie received from your backend

                // Extract the cookie name and the value from the first entry in the 
                // setCookie object
                const [cookieName, cookieValue] = Object.entries(setCookie)[0] as [
                    string,
                    string
                ];

                // set the values that you need for your cookie
                cookies().set({
                    name: cookieName,
                    value: cookieValue,
                    httpOnly: true, // the parsing of httpOnly returns an empty string, so either have some logic to set it to boolean, or set it manually
                    maxAge: parseInt(setCookie["Max-Age"]),
                    path: setCookie.Path,
                    sameSite: "strict",
                    expires: new Date(setCookie.Expires),
                    secure: true,
                });

                // return the user object if the response was okay, or null if it wasn't
                ...
            }
        })
    ]
}

export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth(authConfig);
```

[This discussion](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/discussions/4428#discussioncomment-7260401) can help shed more light if you're still stuck.

Answer (score -2):

You need to configure `clientAxios` to include cookies that the server sends as part of its response in all requests back to the server. Setting  `api.defaults.withCredentials = true;` should get you what you want. See the axios configuration for my vue application below:

```
import axios from "axios";

export default ({ Vue, store, router }) => {
  const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL
  });
  api.defaults.withCredentials = true; ------> this line includes the cookies
  Vue.prototype.$axios = api;
  store.$axios = api;
};
```

Comment: The login request is made server side by next-auth, i have the cookies available in any server side call, but client side calls fail